# Sorting algorithm to sort the height of 1.14 billion people!

Tags: sorting

This is an interview question: Given the 1.14 billion population of India,what is the most effective/efficient sorting algorithm that can be used to sort them by their heights?(Heights data is available to you).

Comment: quick sort would be fine if they can all be held in memory at once. And out of memory sort will be required.

Comment: Why will an out of memory sort be required?  The question doesn't state hardware requirements, so why can't you simply use hardware that has memory for 1.14 billion entries?

Comment: The quicksort algorithm can be used on an out-of-memory set.  Common implementations might not be able to, but there's no reason the algorithm could not work with e.g. mmapped memory.

Comment: There are generally so many better alternatives to quicksort though... just because it has the trendy name :-/

Comment: What exactly do you need? "Sort quantitized heigths" or "Sort list of people by heigthts"?

Comment: @cdhowie: my guess is that the interviewer was getting at the fact that the normal `Ω(n×log n)` lower bound for sorting does not apply in this case, which makes quicksort horribly inefficient. (You can do it in `Θ(n+k)`)

Answer (score 10):

O(n):

If heights can be rounded to nearest mm, then you can compute a histogram of heights and print out the counts in each histogram bucket in order.  The expected RAM required is only a few KB for about 2000 32-bit ints.

Answer (score 4):

As the range of possible heights is fairly small, I recommend:

1. Express all the heights in millimeters.
2. Make one pass through the data calculating the min and max heights.
3. Allocate bins for very height between the min and max.
4. Make a second pass through the data adding the people to the appropriate bins.

That's two passes through the dataset, plus the bin allocations.  O(n).

Comment: There is no need in first iteration, I garantee that the values will be between 0 and 3000mm.

Comment: Step 2 is hardly necessary. A little over 2700 bins is enough for 0 to 9 feet in millimeters.

Comment: And in conclusion, you can skip both of them :)

Comment: On time and under budget, bonuses for everyone.

Comment: i agree that determining the correct number of bins is unnecessary, but it only affects the constant factors of the asymptotic time.

Comment: Then the main question: You are sorting people records. What if they don't fit in RAM?

Comment: @ruslik: that's the worst thing about the question - the title suggests only the heights need be sorted, while "sort them by their heights" suggests there's other identifying information therewith.  Still, seems reasonable (though for how many years?) to assume a 32-bit person ID... can reload other data post sort.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the interviewer assumes that the number of different heights is significantly smaller than the number of people, which means that a *counting sort* would be appropriate, which has a worst-case step complexity of `Θ(n+k)`, where `n` is the number of people and `k` is the number of heights.

Because counting sort is not a comparison sort, the typical `Ω(n×log n)` lower bound does not apply, which is probably what the interviewer was *really* getting at.

Answer (score 0):

Another linear time option for bounded numeric data is [radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort), which is just a specialized numeric version of [bin sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort).